# Layout not showing in Java class

Tags: android

i created a new xml layout. but 
- Its not showing in the java class when i need to reference it using R.layout.atd. 
- Also the the id of textView and imageView are not shown.

I restarted eclipse. I deleted the xml and recreated it. But its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: post your xml and activity

Comment: Try see import for R is it com.yourprojectpackage.R or android.R ?

Comment: I think you have an error in XML file, ( after reviewing Haresh suggest )

Comment: I found the answer. I made manual entries of my xml layout and the id's of imageView and 
textView in R.java. Its in "gen" folder under the package name. Thanks for the answers friends.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create XML Layout file in res/layout folder.
2. inside `onCreate` of Activity use `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`
3. to reference : `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);`